# how to get both ID and names from Many to Many field in Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

i'm creating a messaging app like Whatsapp. i have a Profile model that has Rooms as Many to many relationship. meaning every user will have a list of rooms in which he is added in their profile database. i'm using Rest Framework to fetch the Room info. i'm getting only ID's of the room every time i fetch from the API's. but it would be much easier & optimized for my app if i could also get Names of the Rooms & ID through the profile's Api which has rooms as many to many relation.
How can i save both Name & id into a Many to Many field??

```
#model.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Room)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from App.models import *



class roomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = '__all__'

class userSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class profileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):



    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from App.models import *
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['name'] = user.username
        # ...

        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer




@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def GetRoomData(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        rooms = Room.objects.all()
        serializer = roomSerializer(rooms,many=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = roomSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getUserData(request):
    profile = User.objects.all()
    serializer = userSerializer(profile,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET','PUT'])
def getProfileData(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=pk)
        serializer = profileSerializer(profile)
    if request.method=='PUT':
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.data['user'])
        serializer = profileSerializer(profile, data=request.data)  
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: As there is ManyToMany relationship between profile and room, no need to save room id and name to that field. you can easily fetch them

Comment: fetch from Room's api? with that, i have to map the whole room info & only iterate the rooms that the user has in his many to many relation db. is this what you're talking about or something else? cz what i'm asking would help me optimize the app a lot without fetching from room api